# Can Turing machines map the natural numbers onto infinite binary strings?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm having troubles to understand uncountability of infinite binary strings.
As far as I understand, we can prove countability of a set $R$ by finding a surjective function $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow R$. And if a set is uncountable, Cantor's diagonalization argument tells us that for any such function $f$, we can find an example $g(f) \in R$, such that $g(f)$ is not contained in the image of $f$, which proves that there exists no such surjective function $f: \mathbb{N}\rightarrow R$.

Now, let's assume $R$ is the set of infinite binary strings $R=\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$ and $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$. In Cantor's diagonalization argument, $g(f)$ would be a function that inverts all the "diagonal entries" $f(i)_i$ of $f$ which could be expressed by the following:
$$
g:f\rightarrow \{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}\\
f\mapsto (1-f(i)_i)_{i=0}^\infty
$$
This guarantees that $g(f) \notin f[\mathbb{N}]$ and thus $f$ cannot be surjective. So far, everything seems clear to me (if there's already a major mistake here - please let me know...)

But now, my troubles start: Let's set $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$ equal to a Turing machine that maps a program code (encoded in $\mathbb{N}$) to some infinite binary string $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$ (this might take an infinite amount of time...). Then, I cannot find a function $g:f\rightarrow \{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$, that finds me an example that is not contained in the image $f[\mathbb{N}]$. The reason is, that any $g(f)$ itself could be written as a program code (let's call this code $P(g(f))$), which then could be fed back into $f$ and thus, $g(f)$ must be contained in the image of $f$:
$$
P: g(f)\rightarrow\mathbb{N}\\
g(f) \mapsto P(g(f)) \textrm{ such that }g(f) = f(P(g(f))) \in f(\mathbb{N})
$$

For example, the function $g$ that I mentioned above for Cantor's diagonalization argument could be transferred easily into a program code. The "recursion" $f(P(g(f)))$ also shouldn't be a problem, as Turing machines can emulate themselves.

So, if I cannot find a function $g(f)$, that disproves surjectivity of a Turing machine - would this mean, that a Turing machine can map $\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$ in a surjective manner? This would be clearly a contradiction to our previous statement that $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$ is uncountable...

So here comes my actual question: (Where) am I doing something wrong?

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: You will have $f(P(g(f)))\neq g(f)$ precisely because $g(f)\notin f[\mathbb N]$. Why do you assume $f(P(g(f)))= g(f)$?

Comment: Hi Christoph, thanks for your reply! The idea was that we can formulate the computation of $g(f)$ again as a program that we can feed into the Turing machine. Could this be a problem?

Comment: How should a turing machine map a natural number to an infinite binary string ? If a turing machine halts, it will return a finite bit string. And even if this would be possible, why should this map be surjective ?

Comment: Why would $g(f)$ be computable with one of your $\mathbb N$-encoded programs?

Comment: @Peter: Thanks a lot for your reply! My intuition was, that there shouldn't be a problem of letting $f$ run forever - e.g. to produce some repeating (or pseudorandom) patterns... The idea, why $f$ should be surjective was that we cannot find a function $g(f)$ that disproves surjectivity of $f$ (but there's certainly something wrong in my reasoning...).

Comment: @Christoph: Thanks! I guess this was indeed the problem! :) My intuition was that $g(f)$ has to be computable by a $\mathbb{N}$-encoded program - otherwise we could never know, which counterexample $g$ comes up with. However, if I understand correctly, this was a mistake and $g(f)$ does not have to be computable. Then, we can say that $g(f)$ is able to produce results in $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$ - even if it's not computable - while $f(P(g(f)))$ is not allowed to do that. Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: I think we settled that there is no $P$ satisfying your needs, so making statements about $f(P(g(f)))$ is meaningless.

Comment: Is this really true? At least, if we set $g$ as in Cantor's argument, it should be possible to construct a code $P(g(f))$ that inverts all the diagonal entries $f(i)_i$. So I thought, the real problem was that we cannot compute $f(P(g(f)))$... thanks for correcting me, if I'm wrong! ;)

Comment: Cantor's argument shows that there can't be an $n\in\mathbb N$ with $f(n)=g(f)$. This tells you that no $\mathbb N$-encoded program will give you $g(f)$. In other words there can't be a $P(g(f))$ such that $f(P(g(f)))=g(f)$, since if that would be true, setting $n=P(g(f))$ would contradict Cantor's argument.

Comment: Okay, maybe it's just a detail that I do not understand. If I would try to write a code for a Turing machine that computes $g(f)$, where $g$ is Cantor's diagonalization argument and $f$ is a Turing machine, I would write the following (Pseudocode):
for i=0,...,infty: 
1.: emulate a Turing machine with input code i; 
2.: invert the ith value of the string returned by the turing machine; 
3.: set the ith return value to that value;
This code $P$ should exist and can be encoded in $\mathbb{N}$. So I thought, the real problem is, that this $P$ is not computable...

Comment: You're confusing two different things. Once you define $f$ in a particular way, Cantor's diagonalization gives you a new element that your $f$ won't achieve. Your problem is that your $f$ is vague (as in "some Turing machine") and I think that is making it difficult for you to see the problem. It's not that $g$ is not "computable", it's that $f$ should be fixed, and you are not properly fixing it. Once you fix it, in whatever way you like, the same $g$ always works to find an element not in the image.